# How can I use Javascript to display an information message next to the mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript

How can I use Javascript to display the information message next to the mouse pointer when the mouse pointer hovers over a link or button? The information will always be next to the mouse pointer until the mouse moves out of the link/button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you would use the following methods:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter#fn
- http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseleave#fn
- http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mousemove#fn
- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Dialog#option-position

Should be relatively clear how to stitch those together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Look at the [`onmousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Event_Handlers) event handling function. It is passed an [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) object which holds properties called `clientX` and `clientY`, which are the mouse coordinates.

Of course, IE does this sort of thing *slightly* differently and will be a pain for you. A Javascript library glosses over these differences and would be easier, but it's not too hard to do it in plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

Jin, [Overlib](http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/) is exactly what you are looking for, and if you got that idea from another website, chances are, that site was using it. The tip/info is always present when hovering over an enabled element - which is overLib's default behavior. It's also easily customisable to one of the many examples on the home page:

http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/